# Swift code: how do you build a Dictionary of Array of String based on Dictionary entry being nil

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, option-type

I have been trying to understand how to do some simple things with Swift using Dictionary and Array types.

I started by trying to write the simple functions below for manipulating a list of strings and bucketing them into the same array when the strings are anagrams of one another..!

Everything here should run in a playground on Xcode.

Questions:

1. Why can I not use toString() to convert Character Array to a String. I have to iterate over the Array of Character and build the string using += ?
2. What is the best way to add an Array to the Dictionary in the fly as I find that the Dictionary is empty for that string index so I need to create a new Array to hold the strings that sage the same letters. The confusion about a Dictionary not holding the types you think but actually holding Type? (that is Option Type - in my case String?, optional String).

See the crazy code below.

```
groupAnagrams(
  listofWords: pass an array of String (immutable)
 )
```

returns
  Dictionary of Array of String (grouped anagrams)
  A summary of numbers of actions taken in a Array of String
  A log of actions taken in an Array of String

Purpose
  Group the words that are anagrams together into buckets
  The func will create a Dictonary indexed on a String that is the order string of characters, e.g.
    ["bats", "stab"] => [ "abst" : ["rats", "stab"] ]

Function charArrayToString

```
func charArrayToString(charArray ca: [Character]) -> String {
    var s = ""
    for c in ca {
        s += String(c)
    }
    return s
}

func groupAnagrams(#listOfWords: [String]) -> [String:[String]] {
    var s = ""
    var d: [String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()
    var i = 0, j = 0, k = 0
    var log = [String]()

    for s in listOfWords {
        var s1:[Character] = [Character](s)
        //    var s1 = s
        sort(&s1) { (a: Character, b: Character) -> Bool in return String(a) < String(b) }
//???        var s2 = toString(s1) // converts the Array of Character to a string (but it's for the for "[a,b,c,d]" and not "abcd" as you'd expect!
        var s3 = charArrayToString(charArray: s1)
        // Array already exists, add a string ELSE create the String array [String]() and add the fisst element
        if let p = d[s3] {
            // Array exists but d[s3] is "immutable" as it's optional array of String (type [String]?)
            ++i
            var arr = d[s3]!
            arr += [s]
            d[s3] = arr
            log += "Add string \(arr.count) \(s) to array \(s3) \n"
        } else {
            // ELSE: Create new String array
            ++j
            d[s3] = [String]()
            var arr = d[s3]!
            arr += [s]
            d[s3] = arr
            log += "Create array for \(s3) with string \(s) \n"
        }
        ++k
        //    break
    }


    var summary = [String]()
    summary += ["\(i) strings added to already created arrays"]
    summary += ["\(j) arrays created"]
    summary += ["\(k) words processed"]

    summary[0] // inspect
    summary[1] // inspect
    summary[2] // inspect

    log // inspect

    return d
}
```

// Same as the array version of the function but just adds stings to the paratner list of the function

```
func groupAnagramsList(strings: String...) -> [String:[String]] {
    return groupAnagrams(listOfWords: strings)
}
```

Calls to the various functions created:

```
var listOfWords = [String]() + ["bats", "star", "tree", "stab", "rats", "reet", "pong", "peel", "leep", "path", "type", "pyte", "ypte"]

var anagrams = groupAnagrams(listOfWords: listOfWords)

var otherWay = groupAnagramsList("bats", "star", "tree", "stab", "rats", "reet", "pong", "peel", "leep", "path", "type", "pyte", "ypte")
```

UPDATE FROM Swift Beta 5:

```
if d[s3] == nil {
    d[s3] = [String]()
    ++j
} else {
    ++i
}
d[s3]! += [s]
log += ["Add string \(d[s3]!.count) \(s) to array \(s3) \n"]
```

The check for nil on the Dictionary d is valid! In this context the complicated optional / immutable behavior is gone and the code is much easier to understand.
Note: I had to change

log += "Add string (d[s3]!.count) (s) to array (s3) \n"

To:

log += ["Add string (d[s3]!.count) (s) to array (s3) \n"]

Because you now need to explicitly add an Array of String to an Array of String. You cannot assume that += on a String will append a String to the Array. But it's easy, just wrap the string in '[' and ']'.

I still don't know why I cannot just cast a Character Array to a String!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a smart thing would be to use Swift's built-in Objective-C APIs to eliminate duplicate values. E.g:

```
let unique = NSSet(array: swiftArrayOfNonUniqueStrings).allObjects
```

The problem is, applying this to your character-sorted, duplicates-containing string array will just return the character-sorted version of your original string. (You can obtain such an array by returning `alphaList` below.)

As for sorting the characters within the string, I believe that iterating through the characters to build the string is efficient enough. You can write this a bit more succinctly

```
func alphabetizeStrings(list : [String]) -> [String] {   
    var newlist = [String]()
    var alphaList = [String]()
    for s in list {
        var charArray = [Character](s)
        charArray.sort({ (a: Character, b: Character) -> Bool in return String(a) < String(b)})
        var sortedString = ""
        for c in charArray {
            sortedString += c
        }
        if NSArray(array: alphaList).containsObject(sortedString) == false {
            newlist.append(s)
        }
        alphaList.append(sortedString)
    }
    return newlist
}
```

Thus:

```
let swiftarray = ["foo", "foo", "bar", "bra", "bat"]
let unique = alphabetizeStrings(swiftarray)
// ["foo", "bar", "bat"]
```